# Proving that if $(x_n,y_n)$ converges to $(x,y) \in \mathbb R^2$, then $\{x_n\},\{y_n\}$ each converge to $x,y\in\mathbb R$ respectively.

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, metric-spaces, proof-writing

> Prove that if $(x_n,y_n)$ converges to $(x,y) \in \mathbb R^2$, then $\{x_n\},\{y_n\}$ each converge to $x,y\in\mathbb R$ respectively.

I'm having some difficulty understanding how to prove this.

**PROOF**: Let $\rho$ be a metric for $\mathbb R^2$ and $\tau$ be a metric for $\mathbb R$. If $(x_n,y_n) $ converges to $ (x,y) \in \mathbb R^2$, then by definition, for any $\epsilon >0$ there exists $N \in \mathbb N$ such that for all $n\ge N$, $$\rho\left((x_n,y_n), (x,y)\right) < \epsilon.$$ **Here's where I'm stuck**: Does this imply that given any $\epsilon > 0$, we may take the same $N\in\mathbb N$ such that for all $n\ge N$ to give us $$\tau(x_n, x) < \epsilon \;\;\;\;\text{and}\;\;\;\;\tau(y_n,y) < \epsilon?$$ This seems to make (obvious) sense, but it just feels not rigorous enough to separate a point in $\mathbb R^2$ into its components like this. In other words: it seems natural *to want* to separate it, but are we even allowed to formally *prove* it this way?

> I also need to go in the opposite direction (since this is an iff proof), which means I would need to combine them somehow in that case; i.e., take $N = \max\{N_1, N_2\}$ for some $N_1,N_2\in\mathbb N$ when doing an $\epsilon-N$ proof for both sequences individually. But this is not the part of the proof I have a question on right now.

Comment: You need to define a [product metric](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Product_metric) in $\Bbb R^2$. The natural product metric is the [Chebyshev distance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chebyshev_distance) (but not the unique) because we have that an open ball in $\Bbb R^2$ defined by the cartesian product of two open balls of $\Bbb R$ define this metric.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't pick arbitrary metrics, there must be some relationship between the
metric on $\mathbb{R}^2$ and $\mathbb{R}$.

I am assuming that  you are using the usual (Euclidean) metric on $\mathbb{R}^2$.

Then $|x| \le \sqrt{x^2+y^2}$ and similarly for $y$.

Then $|x-x_n| \le \sqrt{ (x-x_n)^2+(x-y_n)^2}$ and similarly for $y$.

For the other direction, note that
$\sqrt{x^2+y^2} \le \sqrt{2} \max (|x|,|y|)$.

Comment: This is obvious if we use the usual Euclidean metric on $\mathbb R^2$ (i.e., the $\ell^2$ norm), but I wasn't sure if we had to remain general with our metrics$.

Comment: Then you need to relate the two metrics in some way. For example, if you take the metric on the reals to be the discrete metric, then it is easy to construct a counterexample.

Comment: As an addendum for those coming here in the future, there was a line of text I missed in my textbook--when the metric is not specified, we need to use the usual concept of distance in Euclidean space--so $\displaystyle \left(\sum_{n=1}^\infty x_i^2\right)^{1/2}$ and $|x_1-x_2|$...